# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I had `SwiftyJson` installed via `cocoapods`. Then i removed it accidentally then installed it again now it is giving me this error. I really don't know what to do now. I tried everything. But no use. Anybody can with any clues or hints?

[image]

Comment: How did your reinstall it ? through `cocoapods`  ?

Comment: @Wongzigii yes through cocoapods

Comment: Remove that line a.k.a `pod SwiftyJSON` from the Podfile, run `pod install`. after it, re-add and re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project, it usually fixes problems like this, in your tool bar go to `Product > Clean` or press `shift + cmd + k`

otherwise reinstall your cocoapods with `pod install` in terminal while in the directory of your project

Comment: hmm, can you post the error it shows when you try to run the app

Comment: here you are i updated my question. What happened is that i tried to add alamofire with cocoapods but what happened that swiftyJson was erased. So i erased both and tried to add swiftyJson alone again. But didn't work. By the way i have to working branches the master and another branch but i don't have branches for the pods. Maybe this could be a reason. I have a lot of issues because of this branches thing. But now unfortunately both branches are giving me the same error.

Comment: so when you added alamofire with cocopods did you keep swiftyjson in your .podfile? also I asumme you are using the xcworkspace file as oppsed to the xcproject? and when you say erasing the framework what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I use those two frameworks in my current project from cocoapods aswell, the wording of your last comment leads me to beleive that maybe you deleted swiftyJSON, you must keep both in the podfile

Comment: I will try that using my app target name. Anyway all my problems started after using source control and when i tried to change my app's name. But i resolved that issue yesterday. Now when the swiftyjson pod was removed accidentally i have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank all who helped me to solve this issue. I just wanted to say that i resolved the case. All the problem was that i had old pod dependency files left in the `.xcodeproj` original file. So every time the pod was installed the `.xcworkspace` used the old pod file within the schema. So i had to delete the old files completely from the `.xcodeproj` first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clean your

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

folder for your project

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with Alamofire and other libraries. I try a lot of ways it was not success.

Swift legacy versions must be same with your target, I use Swift 2.3 each target and library. I explain with images below, I hope someone use this.

1. Select your pod project and your library
2. Select Build Settings
3. Set Use legacy swift language version to YES (it is 2.3)
4. Select your project target
5. Repeat again 3. step

clean & build, that is!

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

Answer (score -1):

Please confirm that you have dragged the pod.xcodeproj  into your main project.If not, do steps as below.

1.To find the root of your main project in Finder.
Shortcut: Right Click your view file -> Show in finder

2.Add the Pod.xcodeproj in your main project  [Click to look at the picture]

[Add the Pod project in your main proj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrc23.png)

3.Product -> clean

4.Rebuild